# Value passed in component input changing parent

Tags: angular

As I understand it, the `Input` fields in a component are supposed to be one directional (parent to child). However, I have a value I'm passing into an `Input` and then modifying it in the component, but I'm noticing it changes in the parent as well. That makes some sense to me, as objects are passed by reference, but I'm guessing that means that the whole "one way binding" thing Angular sets is just a paradigm, not strict? Angular does nothing under the hood to enforce one way binding?

Basically, I'm doing:

```
<session-form [values]="session"></session-form>
```

In the `session-form` component, I change `session.start` from a unixtimestamp to a Moment object. But I then notice in the parent, `session.start` is also a Moment object.

Is there a paradigm for using data like this? Should I be copying input values to a variable scoped strictly to the component once it's set?

Answer (score 2):

Look into the smart/dumb (container/presentational) component architecture.

Basically the idea is that smart components contain the state of your app or talk to a service that contains the state.  The dumb components just render the data given to it from the @Input.  The smart components pass the state to the dumb component.

Instead of directly updating the data in the dumb component you use an event emitter to tell the smart component to update the data.  This way you have the one way data flow.

More info here:
http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's an interesting way of doing it, though in this case, I'm looking more to keep the component completely separate; it's basically formatting the data it receives into a format it prefers. I don't see how it makes sense to ask the parent to format it's data for it.

Comment: If it's just formatting, you could probably use the date pipe: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe.  Or build a custom pipe that does the moment work.

Comment: Is this still the case, or does not update its parent's data, now? because it's not updating the parent for me, and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's changed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, objects are passed by reference. However, you should not bind properties of your object to the form using `[(ngModel)]` because it's two-way binding and since object is passed by reference it reflects the changes to it inside the parent component as well. You should instead create a `FormGroup` and pass the object values to it using a `FormBuilder.group()` function since it's one directional.

```
// Inside of your child component
@Input() myInput: SomeClass;

form: FormGroup

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) { }    

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        prop1: [this.myInput.prop1],
        // etc.
    });
}
```

Comment: As I showed above, I'm not using two way binding. I'm using one way with `[value]`. Also, I am using a FormGroup in the component, but I need to modify the data for use outside the form as well.

Comment: @RhoVisions I know that you're passing input one way with `[value]`, but as you said it's reference to an object and if you bind any of it's properties with two-way binding inside your child component, it will be reflected to the parent component. `FormGroup` prevents you from doing so. If you need two-way binding inside your child component outside the form, you will need to do so yourself. For example, create a variable within a component named `private prop1: string;` and inside `ngOnInit` assign the value from an object to that variable `this.prop1 = myObj.prop1`, now you can bind it 2-way

Comment: @RhoVisions I assume you're binding that data outside the form using `[(ngModel)]` at the moment inside your child component. :)

Comment: In my component, I'm modifying the data that comes in via `[value]` (converting a timestamp to a Moment object), which I need for display purposes in the child component. Even though it's one way, I'm seeing the parent component's value also changing to a Moment object, which makes sense from a reference POV, but I didn't realize would happen with a one way binding. At no point am I using two way bindings; I'm using all dynamic forms.

Comment: @RhoVisions My point is, you're changing the properties of an object directly and as you said yourself, object is passed by reference. You should first store object property to separate variable, modify it and then use that variable instead of object property.

Comment: Heh, so sorry if I wasn't clear from the start: I'm asking about paradigms/patterns for that. If it's just as simple as set values in a setter/onChange, then I've already changed to that.