# Variable assigned from @Input variable also changes assigned variable

Tags: angular, input

In Angular6, i am getting a variable value to client from Parent using @Input()

```
@Input() orderdata: OrderData;
```

and binded to a field using [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) function.

In the child component when user changes this variable value (binded) I need to do a validation comparing the new value and old value. How to do this?

I tried assigning orderdata to a new variable

```
oldorderdata = orderdata;
```

and then later perform the comparison. But when ever user changes the orderdata at the moment itself oldorderdata is also changed.

Comment: Did you check [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), especially `OnChanges`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you assign objects to each other in JS, you're not assigning their values, you're just assigning to their memory references.

That's why when the `orderdata` is changed, the `oldorderdata` will also change since it was pointing to the same object in memory.

To prevent this, you can use the spread operator(`...`) in ES6 like this:

```
oldorderdata = {...orderdata};
```

This will spread all the properties from orderdata into the oldorderdata object.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. Above solution plus declaring the oldorderdata as private (as advised in discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058145/value-passed-in-component-input-changing-parent?rq=1) resolved the problem

Comment: Glad I helped!!

Answer (score 0):

the variable will generally change since you are binding it with [(ngModel)], to make the comparison you need to bind the variable to output of the comparison function instead

Comment: I ngModel binding on orderdata variable and there is no binding on oldorderdata. How change in orderdata is changing the oldorderdata?